# Rails 5: dynamically get the model name to create versions with Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I'm trying to dynamically create a version of a Carrierwave image if the polymorphic association is of a certain model, and skip it otherwise.

For instance:

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**listing.rb**

```
class Listing < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**picture.rb**

```
class Picture < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
  validates :image, presence: true
  validates_integrity_of :image
end
```

I'm trying to do the following in the uploader:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Only do this if model type is Listing
  version :card do
    process resize_to_fit: [800, 800]
    process resize_to_fill: [640, 430]
  end

  # Only do this if model type is User
  version :profile do
    process resize_to_fit: [600, 600]
  end

  def extension_whitelist
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
end
```

I've tried with `version :profile, if: :is_user? do` and then creating a method like:

```
def is_user?(picture)
  model.imageable_type.downcase == 'user'
end
```

but `model.imageable_type` is nil when a Picture is still not saved.

I am overwriting Devise's update method to add images to users:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def update
    super do
      pics = params[:user][:pictures]
      if pics.present?
        pics.each { |pic| resource.pictures << Picture.new(image: pic) }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I've also tried with:

```
def update
  super do
    pics = params[:user][:pictures]
    if pics.present?
      pics.each { |pic| resource.pictures.build(image: pic) }
    end
  end
end
```

and

```
def update
  super do
    pics = params[:user][:pictures]
    if pics.present?
      resource.pictures = pics.map { |pic| Picture.new(image: pic) }
    end
  end
end
```

and for listings I am creating images like this:

```
class ListingsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @listing = Listing.new(JSON.parse(params[:listing]))
    @listing.owner = current_user
    @listing.pictures = params[:file].values.map { |file| Picture.new(image: file) }

    respond_to do |format|
      if @listing.save
        format.html { redirect_to listing_path(@listing), notice: 'Listing was created successfully!' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @listing }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @listing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Is there a way to dynamically get the model name to create versions so that I don't have to create new uploaders for each model (which seems to defeat the purpose of having a polymorphic Picture model in my opinion).
Thanks in advance!

Comment: try `model.imageable_type.is_a?(User)` and can you add the code of the controller action for creating the image?

Comment: Hi @ZivGalili I've added the controller methods that add the images.
Also, I tried your suggestion but `model.imageable_type` gives me `nil` so `model.imageable_type.is_a?(User)` always returns false.

Comment: i think you should use `build` when creating new Pictures right on the associated model. so instead of doing `<< Picture.new(image: pic)` you should do something like: `resource.pictures.build(image: pic)` - that way the created picture is already associated with the `resource` model, so in the uploader `imageable_type` should have a value. (in your way, when doing `Picture.new` you don't associate any model to it, so `imageable_type` is `nil`, you can also do `Picture.new(image: file, imageable: resource)` i think, but go for the first method).

Comment: `model.imageable_type` is still nil, even if I do `resource.pictures.build(image: pic)`. I think this is because polymorphic models don't get the imageable_type and id until they are validated (so it happens right before committing I believe.) I definitely thought this would be easier hehe...

Comment: hmm thats weird. when i try in my console this: `c = Article.new.comments.new` (where `Comment` is a polymorphic association named `commentable`) i wont get the `Article` when i try `c.commentable` because its not saved to the db, as your problem, BUT when i do `c.commentable_type` he gives me the correct model name back `"article"`. Can you try in your `rails console` to do: `listing = Listing.new.pictures.new` and then `listing.imageable_type` and tell me the result?

Comment: That returns `"Listing"` which is correct. Unfortunately I cannot get that from the scope of `def is_listing?`. `model.imageable_type` gives me `nil`. `self.imageable_type` gives me `NameError`.

Comment: Can you add the edited controller actions to the question? (with the `build`). And another thing, just give it a try - restart the server after you make that `build` change. (it doesn't really need to make difference, but just give it a try :P )

Comment: I've updated the question with the `build` for a User. I restarted the server but it made no difference :(